# Encryption in blackberry and decryption in .net webservices

Tags: c#, .net, blackberry, webserver

My BlackBerry app needs to send encrypted data to a .NET webservice, which will decrypt the data.

Please share your ideas on how to do this.

Comment: To ask the obvious; can you not use transport security?(https)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I found to securely send data between Java and .NET is to use BouncyCastle (http://www.mobilefish.com/developer/bouncycastle/bouncycastle.html), as you will probably want to use RSA encryption to encrypt the symmetric key, unless you are encrypting a small amount of data.  If you are going to send the encrypted data and a different symmetric key for each session, then this will be your best bet.

You may want to look at this question, to see a brief discussion on using Bouncy Castle on Blackberry:

[BouncyCastle RSA encryption for BlackBerry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846710/how-to-implement-bouncy-castle-rsa-encryption-in-black-berry-application)

This discussion will show how that it should work on the Blackberry:

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/bouncy-castle/m-p/541682

Comment: I know this is old, but I'm trying to do something similar. What are the advantages of implementing this over using https with username+password or some sort of token based authentication?

Comment: @Tejaswi Yerukalapudi - It depends on what you are trying to protect, or what you are doing. I had an application where I needed to pass passwords, and I wanted to verify the client, so I used encryption as the clients each had their own public key, to ensure that only trusted clients were connecting.